# Cambiar usuario en docker con noVNC

Tags: docker

estamos creando una imagen docker que parte de una imagen que contiene instalado el noVNC en root y siempre que arrancamos estamos en el usuario root

¿Se puede cambiar para que sea otro usuario el que arranque el contenedor y por lo tanto el noVNC?

Comment: Más allá del [link de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de recibir una respuesta.
Si has encontrado una respuesta por tu cuenta, puede que te interese ver [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: ¿Te han servido las respuestas? ¿Algo no se entendió? Siempre puedes editar tu pregunta o agregar comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Aclaración, de la [documentación docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface):

> Running containers (and applications) with Docker implies running the
>   Docker daemon. This daemon currently requires root privileges, and you
>   should therefore be aware of some important details.

Es decir el Docker daemon corre con privilegios de `root` y como consecuencia los contenedores corren (en principio) con privilegios de `root`. Por lo que hay que ser sumamente cuidadoso con lo que se hace (*"Un gran poder conlleva una gran responsabilidad"*).

**En el Host (equipo anfitrión)**

Puede que lo quieras en no utilizar el usuario `root` para ejecutar los comandos de Docker, delegando esas tareas a un grupo de usuarios. Hay dos opciones:

1. Utilizando `sudo`. El tema es largo, si no conoces bien el tema te sugiero leer un tutorial, como por ejemplo [este](http://www.linuxtotal.com.mx/?cont=info_admon_014).
2. Crear el grupo `docker` y agregar los usuarios al mismo. Los detalles están en la guía de instalación de `docker`. Por ejemplo para Ubuntu [acá](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/create-a-docker-group)

**En el Container (contenedor)**

Como se menciona arriba el container por defecto ejecuta como `root`, esto puede traerte problemas, por ejemplo si no tienes cuidado en la creación de archivos tendrás a `root` como owner (dueño) y en particular si tienes volúmenes montados sobre el host te podrás encontrar que `root` es owner del archivo tanto en el host como en el container.

Puedes configurar el usuario con el que se ejecuta el contenedor en el Dockerfile mediante la instrucción [`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/user). Por ejemplo:

```
USER novnc
```

Dependiendo de que estés creando la imagen, puede que necesite agregar los usuarios y grupos necesarios, antes de seleccionar el usuario.

```
RUN groupadd -r novnc && useradd -r -g novnc
```

**NOTA:** En Unix los usuarios y grupos se identifican con números (`uids` y `gids`) por lo que para que tengan cierto sentido tanto en el host como en el container, deberías tener hecho algún tipo de mapeo (a nivel de cómo se llaman en un lado y otro).

Referencias (en inglés):

- [Instrucción usuario](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/user)
- [Mejores prácticas - Usuario](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/user)

Comment: Sigo aclarando sobre el tema. Así que probablemente siga editando esta pregunta, mantenganse conectado ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Agrega al usuario que quieras que ejecutar el contenedor al grupo de docker, que generalmente es `docker`.